# Programmatically save or get byte array data (to save by other means) of images on page in any browser without having to redownload them again

Tags: javascript, image, web-scraping, browser, greasemonkey

I'm looking for a way to save the images on a page I'm browsing (scrape-as-you-browse essentially), without making repeated download requests. There are multiple cases where the images simply won't download properly if you try that, and since the browser already has downloaded them once, I feel like there has to be a way to avoid wasting internet traffic and time spent waiting for images, especially large ones, to download again. Maybe there is a way to read them from cache which I haven't found yet.

I've already tried using `canvas` to redraw the images and get the base64-encoded string and getting a binary blob array of bytes, but these methods don't work if there are any CORS restrictions. And also these won't result in the original 1-to-1 image bytes.

Is it possible in any modern browser to get the images which have already been received (as you can see, for example, in Firefox > Tools > Page info > Media tab) without making a second download request?

I would then send the byte array (or base64 encoded string of it) of the source image file to a `localhost` address to save it as a file using a listening app (this part I've already implemented).

---

I'm not looking for browser addons/extensions or which menu buttons to press in browser GUI, but for javascript methods I can call in a userscript via GreaseMonkey (or any other userscript extension that supports a working solution) to get the source image file data.

I've already looked at older questions and they either don't have any working answers or the answers have problems like CORS or lossy canvas redrawing or repeated download requests which may not work, as described above. So if you link to a duplicate, please make sure it has a solution that works without those caveats.

Comment: If an image has been downloaded, and you request the same src again, I'm *pretty sure* the image doesn't get downloaded again, in normal circumstances. If you're having CORS issues with a canvas, my first idea would be to create an iframe on the origin of the image, open the image in that iframe, then communicate the data back up to the parent (or just send the data to localhost)

Comment: The only way to get the current content of a resource without even attempting a download, AFAIK, is to write a chrome extension that uses `chrome.debugger` API with [Page.getResourceContent](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-getResourceContent) command.

Comment: @CertainPerformance hmm thanks for the tip, I'll investigate that and update with results after work.

Comment: @wOxxOm your url leads to a 404 page `Oops you hit a 404!` (maybe it's because I'm using Firefox and this is Chrome documentation so it's not working properly on other browsers, even though it's on github :p)

Comment: His URL works fine for me